# Is orderBy() method in Laravel provides protection against sql injection?

Tags: php, laravel

Is orderBy() method in Laravel provides protection against sql injection?

```
Ex: 
$column = "SUBSTRING_INDEX(material_type, '\\\', -1)";
$sort = 'desc';
DB::table('students')->orderBy(DB::raw($column), $sort)->get();
```

Comment: `DB::table('students')->orderby($column, $sort);` try this

Comment: I am changing query here DB::table('students')->orderby(DB::raw($column), $sort)->get();

Comment: you cant do it via `eloquent` or need `query builder`

Comment: Eloquent uses parameter binding behind the scene, which safely escapes any input used in your query.

Comment: Hey  @Alexander Villalobos, Yes you are right! both Eloquent and Query builder provides protection against sql injection. But I want to make sure that larave orderBy() method gives protection against SQL injection or not. Since I heard some where Laravel provides protection against sql injection when only we use where() method and not for orderBy() and limit() methods etc...

Answer (score 3):

`->orderBy(DB::raw($column), $sort)` is **not** secure, raw expressions are always vulnerable to SQL injections.

You can use `->orderBy($column, $sort)`, but I wouldn't recommend it.

Laravel does **not** use parameter binding for column names because the underlying `PDO` doesn't support it ([reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/182353/4848587)). Parameter bindings can **only** be used for values (`where name = ?`).

Laravel tries to prevent SQL injections through the column name ([reference](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/a8f17c52d2c01289999eba7e5fa893a45b0204e2/src/Illuminate/Database/Grammar.php#L112)), but I wouldn't rely on that. I assume you have a list of allowed column names, so use it as a whitelist:

```
$columns = ['id', 'name', 'created_at', ...];
if(!in_array($column, $columns, true)) {
    // Throw an exception or set $column to a secure default value.
}
```

Laravel uses `asc` as the default direction if the provided value is invalid ([reference](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/51a3c31239931b4720a6105f6e8de1a69c2233d1/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php#L1730)).
So I would say that you don't have to check `$sort` yourself.

Comment: Nice explanation! Well, actually my case is to have sub-query there at the place of $column. So DB::raw($column) came into existence. So query becomes like

$column = 'Some sub-query' pretend $column = 'SUBSTRING_INDEX(material_type, '\\\', -1)'

->orderBy(DB::raw($column), $sort)

Comment: The user can supply *any* value for `$column`?

Comment: I have just updated my question. Please take a look.

Comment: Yes user can supply any value. Pretend $column some times can be 'id', some other time it can be 'created_at' and then next time it can be like "SUBSTRING_INDEX(material_type, '\\\', -1)". It depends on the user input.

Comment: This is a *very* bad idea, you can't implement that securely. You have to find a different solution where you whitelist the allowed column names and functions.

Comment: I have not implemented that dude. Somebody else was implemented that but now I am pulling out my hair. Now I need to change the whole thing.

Comment: Good thing you noticed it. This is a security nightmare.

Answer (score 0):

In Short, YES.

Modify your code from

```
DB::table('students')->orderby(DB::raw($column), $sort);
```

to

```
DB::table('students')->orderBy($column, $sort);
```

Why?

> The Laravel query builder uses PDO parameter binding to protect your
>   application against SQL injection attacks. There is no need to clean
>   strings being passed as bindings.

[Laravel Document](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#introduction)

Answer (score 0):

If you use `DB::raw($text)` then no. what is inside `$text` goes into the query as is.

As suggested, use:

```
DB::table('students')->orderby($column, $sort);
```

in this case, yes the `orderBy()` method in Laravel provides protection against sql injection since the variables will be passed as bindings.

PS: it's the same case for all methods of eloquent. if you use `DB::raw()` you need to be extra careful.

Comment: So ->orderby(DB::raw($column), $sort); also indirectly provides protection against sql injection. Since I have used DB::raw() inside orderBy() method.

Comment: @somu the fact that it works doesnt mean it's correct.